# webpack-dev-server is not always recompiling, rsync issue

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, rsync, inotify

I have a setup where I work on my local machine (MacOS) in IntelliJ, use `rsync` to a remote machine (RHEL 5.3) and have webpack-dev-server running over there.

"All of a sudden" it stopped working properly. Webpack is not recompiling on file changes anymore.

- I was looking at the files on the remote and they are updated.
- I checked the inotify file handles and it has the same amount of files as before,
- I did a `console.log` in watchpack.js and all the files are registered.
- If I use nano on the remote machine and modify a file it instantly triggers a recompilation
- Interestingly, it sometimes (very rarely) triggers if I do a change on my local machine
- Tried sublime as well to block out an IDE issue
- `touch`ing the file on remote triggers a recompile, which I use sort of as a workaround for now

I don't know what exactly could be wrong and because I don't have control over updates in my company I don't know if there was a update that changed e.g. rsync.

Does anyone know whether rsync changes don't trigger inotify events anymore?

Is there anything else I can do to have the file changes recognized again (other than polling?)?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Rsync normally transfers files to a temporary location and then moves them to the final position. This might be confusing the notifications, so you might investigate `--inplace`. Or, you could try turning the machine off and on again.